# Null Screen in React Navigation v5?

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

In React navigation v4 we pass the null screen like this:

```
`Screen: {
            screen: () => null,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarIcon: <AddButton />
            }
        },`
```

But How to I can do it in react navigation 5?

Answer (score 0):

I choose this path for the screens I want to hide. May be help you. I manage isLogin with Mobx.

```
{MenuStore.isLogin ? <></>
                  : <Drawer.Screen
                      name="Login"
                      component={LoginStackScreen}
                    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `<NavigatorName.Screen name="ScreenName">{() => null}</NavigatorName.Screen>` to pass null as a screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event listener on the tab bar

```
<Tab.Screen
          name="Plus"
          component={Add}
          listeners={{
            tabPress: (e) => {
              e.preventDefault(); // — > the main part
            },
          }}
        />
```

Where Add is

```
const Add = () => {   return null; };
```

Comment: I get an error. "e.preventDefault is not a function"